# Как получить содержимое сообщения VK_API Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Использую [`vk_api`](https://github.com/python273/vk_api)

При её использовании, входящие текстовые сообщения получаются исправно, а когда кто - то отправляет стикер / картинку / видео / голосовое, возвращается просто пустое сообщение. Можно ли как - то получить данные медиа (ссылку на них)?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать вот такой метод вк

> "messages.getConversations"